# Difference between Guards and ngIf?

Tags: angular, guard

There are 2 types of users for my web app, normal user and admin.Based upon these user I want control my elements on the page. For example, if a admin logs in we are showing update ,delete option to him but restricting these options for normal users. for for security purpose which is best , Guards or ngIf

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For security, neither. Security is only achieved by securing the backend.

Answer (score 1):

Guard is used for different purpose than ngIf.

Suppose you have three pages namely `Page1`, `Page2`, `Page3`.Now consider that `Page1` can be accessed only by admin whereas `Page2` and `Page3` can be accessed by both admin as well as normal user.So we will add a guard for `Page1` which will check if the user is admin then only it will load the page else it will redirect to other page.

> For example, if a admin logs in we are showing update ,delete option
>   to him but restricting these options for normal users

For this you need ngIf so that based upon user roles you can show/hide the options available as the same page is being accessed by admin/normal user.

> for for security purpose which is best , Guards or ngIf

So both have different purposes according to use case.For security it is better to add a check in backend using `JWT` or any other way.So for any read/write/delete call it will verify if the user has access to it.

Answer (score 0):

Guards are used to to allow navigation to certain routes. So if you have an admin section to your application, that would have a guard that allows only certain users access to that screen, based on their roles and if they do not have those roles, they can be redirected to a Unauthorized page, etc.

`*ngIf` is better used to hide specific items on the page, so for example hiding the admin button in your menu based on whether the user has the required roles.

Hopefully that helps